# Stopping execution of methods created by define_method

Tags: ruby, watir

The following is my program:

```
class Raja < Watir::TestCase
  testName.each_index do |i|  # test case has sequence of test cases.
    define_method(testName[i]) do
    end
  end
end
```

There are ten test cases. First loop runs ten times, so `define_method` will create ten methods like `def test_1`, `def test_2`, ..., `def test_10`. If some error happens at `test_3`, I need to stop the rest of the method from executing further. From `test_4` to `test_10` should not execute. How could I stop this execution?

Comment: Note that you could just do `testName.each do |name| define_method(name)`, instead of `each_index`/`testName[i]`.

Comment: Given the tests are dependent, why not make a single test?

Comment: @JustinKo problem here is, each and every test cases will create a entry in XML , if we make one single test case, then there will be only one entry.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance variable, which would be responsible for knowing whether to execute the method.

```
class Raja < Watir::TestCase
  attr_accessor :execute
  alias_method  :execute?, :execute

  testName.each_index do |i|  # test case has sequence of test cases.
    define_method(testName[i]) do
      return unless execute?

      # Your code here.
    rescue
      self.execute = false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: No no, you are avoiding the execution after we enter into the test cases, that means after enter into the def test_1 but I need to avoid completely, that means further call must be avoided. if it fails at def test_3 and then def test_4 should be avoided. You may ask me why this arrangement, because if 1000 test cases are there, then even if it fails at 2, it need to execute remaining 998 test case.